# How to achieve a 2 way ensured lucky trade where 1 of the traders has already 9 luckys obtained through trading?

Tags: pokemon-go

I plan to make a trade with someone. That person has a shiny magicarp, I would like to have as a lucky form, the other person wants one of my shiny moltress as lucky form.

The problem is, my trade partner has already obtained 9 lucky pokemon.
But I know, one of my first lucky trades I made with someone, that person had aswell already more than 10 luckys, but since I didn't had them, it worked for us both getting a lucky from the trade anyways. I want to use that here for my advantage. So we plan to trade one of my pre 09/2016 pokemon for the other persons magicarp and one of the other persons pre 09/2016 pokemon for my Moltress. The problem is, I can't remember, if it was my pokemon having been from pre august when I made this trade back then and it worked, or it was one of the other person.

So my question is:

Who has to trade in first his pre September 2016 caught pokemon for our plan to work out? Or isn't it important at all, as long one of us hasn't obtained overall 10 lucky pokemon yet?

### Clarification:

I am not asking for how to improve the chances of getting a lucky pokemon or something that alike.

I am asking, if it is relevant, who trades his pre September/2016 pokemon in first, to obtain [the 100% lucky benefit](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2018-09-06-pokemon-go-lucky-pokemon-5392) in the specific scenario I described.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

The person who trades the pre 09/2016 Pokemon must have less than 10 lucky Pokemon to guarantee a 100% lucky rate.

Regarding your proposed trades with your friend:

- Your trade partner, as he has less than 10 (9), can trade a pre
  09/2016 Pokemon for a guaranteed lucky Pokemon, though sadly his
  shiny Magikarp won't be pre 09/2016 (shinies weren't available then).
  If he doesn't trade a pre 09/2016, then trading one of your 09/2016
  will only guarantee it if you have less than 10 luckies
- Him trading one of his pre 09/2016 Pokemon for your Moltres will work.
  Note he will then have 10 lucky Pokemon. and him trading with a pre
  09/2016 Pokemon again no longer guarantees a lucky Pokemon.

Comment: Its someone I trust so we agreed on a 2 way trade. Me having yet just gotten 8 luckys and the other person having got 9. So if we first trade the pre Sep pokemon for my Moltress and after that my pre Sep Pokemon for the shiny magicarp it will work out then, did I get that right?

Comment: Yes that will work

Answer (score 0):

Trading for a "lucky" Pokémon from my experience, works best with age. The older the Pokémon (in terms of how long ago you caught them), the higher the chance that the Pokémon will be lucky when you trade it.

> Although Pokémon turn into Lucky Pokémon at random when traded, the longer you have a Pokémon, the greater the chances that they will become Lucky Pokémon.

<sup>[Niantic Support](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001762007-Lucky-Pok%C3%A9mon)</sup>

That works both ways - regardless of whether or not a Pokémon is/isn't already lucky, it (should) be when you trade it. So in the case of both Pokémon being 2 years old, you have a very high chance of both being lucky in the same trade.

Comment: There is a feature/event/whatever, That says, if you haven‘t obtained 10 luckys yet, and trade a pokemon caught before September 2016 it is guranteed(!) that its gonna create a lucky pokemon.